# Rubymine - Keyboard shortcut to switch between console tabs

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

On using rubymine, I often use keyboard shortcut to switch from editor to terminal window. But I can't switch between opening console tabs. If only I could switch between terminal tabs, I don't have to reach to the mouse/touchpad!

[image]

Comment: Try Alt-Left/Right

Comment: no it will move caret to next words

Comment: It's the same shortcut as you would use for switching tabs in the Editor. Check what you have assigned to `Window | Editor Tabs | Select Next/Previous Tab` actions. Try assigning different shortcut is default does not work. Default `Alt + Left/Right` work fine here on Windows 10. But it may also depend on the Terminal settings in IDE (`Settings/Preferences | Tools | Terminal`)

Answer (score 2):

I know that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd> is the default, just can't work on Mac. So instate, as LazyOne suggest, I look inside `Windows | Editor Tabs | Select Next/Previous Tab` and I see another option:

- <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> for next tab
- <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> for previous tab

Pretty neet!
[image]